# Connecting Frontend with Backend in Docker-Compose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

so I am building a web app with react in the frontend and node.js in the backend, to run my API. Because both services were running on the same address, I specified "proxy": "http://localhost:8081" in my package.json and everything worked fine. Now I want to use Docker to manage the deployment of my app and I packaged, both my apps and started them with docker-compose, but for some reason my frontend is not able to send the requests correct. The console keeps saying:
" Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/tags/ from localhost to http://localhost:8081"

What is the best solution to connect my frontend with my backend in a Docker environment?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: You need to use `http://<servicename>:8081` in your `package.json`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can (or should) 2 docker containers interact with each other via localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551966/can-or-should-2-docker-containers-interact-with-each-other-via-localhost)