# In docker-compose, how do I expose another service as if it's on localhost?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose I have two services `a` and `b`. I want `a` to be able to access `b` as if it were on localhost.

I have tried using aliases, but it does not seem to work.

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  a: 
    image: my/image:1.2.3
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      B_SERVICE_URL: http://localhost:8443
    depends_on:
      b:
        condition: service_started

  b:
    image: my/otherimage:1.2.3
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - a
          - localhost # Expose as localhost
```

Is this possible using Docker Compose?
If so, how?

---

Edit: I also need service `b` to be accessible on the host machine at `localhost:8443`

---

This question [docker compose: how to reference other service as localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316025/docker-compose-how-to-reference-other-service-as-localhost) is not a duplicate because it concerns accessing the host's "localhost" on `localhost`. I want to access another Docker service as `localhost` from inside a different Docker service.

Comment: `localhost` has a special meaning; in Docker, it almost always means "the current container".  The best approach to this is to remove the hard-coded host name (what if you need to scale up and run these two programs on separate hardware?), but the linked question has a couple of other workarounds.

Comment: The linked question is subtly different to my one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare that containers share a single network namespace using the [`network_mode`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode) option in your compose file, like this:

```
services:
  a: 
    image: my/image:1.2.3
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      B_SERVICE_URL: http://localhost:8443

  b:
    image: my/otherimage:1.2.3
    network_mode: service:a
```

Now `localhost` in service A means the same thing as `localhost` in service B. Note that we can only set up port forward in service A in this case, and we cannot give B a unique alias or attach it to other networks -- from a networking perspective, A and B are now the same thing.

---

**Update**: [Here](https://asciinema.org/a/zfx4MAg99895YEIIHFhGyHf6N) is an example showing the above configuration, demonstrating that we can port forward services in A and B by setting the correct configuration on service A.

Comment: This almost works (thanks for showing `network_mode: service:a`, the docs are very limited in that respect!). However, this prevents `b` from being accessible on `localhost:8443` on the host machine.

Comment: That is untrue. By configuring the port forwarding on service A, as I discussed in the answer, we are exposing any service in A or B listening on port 8443 on `localhost:8443` on the host. You can set up whatever port forwarding you want; you simply have to configure it on A rather than on B.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. My mistake!

Comment: Success! However, I did things slightly differently in the end. I created a Caddy proxy in `network_mode: service:a` to access service `b` from inside of service `a`, but without losing a unique host for `b` (this is better for other services).

I have added the snippet to your answer - please edit as you see fit!

Comment: That is an alternative solution and maybe worth it's own answer, because it's a different configuration than what I've discussed here.