# Accessing localhost port of one docker container inside another docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I want to access service1 from inside of service2 container by using `localhost:5432`. How can do so?

This is what my docker compose currently looks like:

```
services:
  service1:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - '172.10.1.1:5432:5432'
    expose:
      - '5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=project
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  service2:
        build: .
        ports:
          - '172.10.1.1:1234:1234'
```

Please note I know i can access it by using `service1:5432` or just `service1`. But I would like to use `localhost` if possible.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547795/how-to-share-localhost-between-two-different-docker-containers  You can do it in a hacky way but this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to use localhost?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because each container has a own ip.

But there is a workaround:
Set network to host. So the ports are open on hostmaschine and are accessible via `127.0.0.1`. Not working on windows.

But I don't know any good reason why you like to use `localhost` for postgres? Are you trying to authenticate via `localhost`? Don't do that - use a password instead.

Answer (score -1):

### Using host network maybe a solution you are finding
https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

```
services:
  service1:
    image: postgres:12
    network_mode: host
    expose:
      - '5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=project
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  service2:
    build: .
    network_mode: host
```